# ¿Cómo puedo ponerle borde intermitente a un div sin que me afecte el div con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Necesito que me dispare un borde de color rojo en un select (que tengo dentro de un div), repetidamente, lo intenté con la function "setInterval", pero me afecta el div también, es decir, me esconde y muestra el div también.. pero necesito que lo haga es con el borde solamente..
Éste fue el último fragmento que programé, pero quedé en las mismas..

```
setInterval(function(){ cambiarbord(eldiv).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200); });

function cambiarbord(eso){

    return eso.css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"})
}
```

Gracias infinitas a cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Creo que el problema puede ser el selector. Este deberia de ser algo como $('div > select'). Si esta afectando a otro elemento es porque también cumple con el selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución puede ser crear dos funciones y llamarlas una a la otra con un determinado intervalo de tiempo en el ejemplo 750ms

```
function bordeRojo(div) {
  div.css({ border: "2px solid red" });
  setTimeout(function() {
    bordeTransparente(div);
  }, 750);
}

function bordeTransparente(div) {
  div.css({ border: "2px solid transparent" });
  setTimeout(function() {
    bordeRojo(div);
  }, 750);
}

bordeRojo($("#borde"));
```

si querés que haga un efecto de fade in fade out además deberías setearle la transición al div mediante css por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
#borde {
  transition: border-color 0.75s;
}
```

Hay que notar que la duración de la transición css es de la misma cantidad de tiempo que tienen los timouts de javascript

**Bonus: Versión 100% css**

Cualquier elemento que tenga esta clase va a hacer que su borde aparezca y desaparezca

```
.borde2 {
  animation: blink 1.5s infinite;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-color 0.75s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Ambos ejemplos funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/52rz8p56mn

Comment: muchas gracias amigo por la solución, hay que admitir que fue una ingeniosa respuesta después de tantos métodos y funciones con que me puse a inventar.. pero ahora tengo otro problemilla.. como podría reutilizar el código de la segunda función "bordeTransparente", para suspender la ejecución del setTimeout del rojo, y dejar el borde transparente, lo que necesito es que el borde quede normal (Transparente), al realizar otro evento. Gracias amigo de antemano, estoy atento.